# Efficient database design for multiple product price based on range of quantity

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I have product and product_price table to store the details.

```
Table Product
id_product| name    | ....
1         | abcd    | ....

Table Product_price
id_price  | id_product  | qty     | price_type            | price
1         | 1           | 20      | percentage_discount   | 10
2         | 1           | 50      | price_discount        | 2
```

Each product may consist of different unit price when user order reached certain amount.

The product_price table show above will discount based on retail price. If bought more than 20 qty considered as wholesale price.

Or i should just do like this

```
Table Product_price
id_price  | id_product  | qty     | unit_price
1         | 1           | 1       | 12
2         | 1           | 20      | 10
3         | 1           | 50      | 9
```

I want to do something like retail price and wholesale price on the product. When user bought in bulk then user will get the wholesale price. If not in bulk then user will stick to the retail price. It's based on quantity purchased.

Is there any flaw for the design or any better approach to make it better? Thanks.

Comment: How are your first 2 designs used in the business? They are not obviously variations of each other. How should we know which one would meet your needs? Also: It's not clear what your "something like" design is. Give it exactly. Also that is a second question that should be in a second post. PS "Efficient" & "better" don't mean anything unless you define them exactly.

Comment: @philipxy I want to do like rule condition which apply discount when purchased quantity meet the rule and apply discount accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this would be to have a qty range. So 1-5 might have one price, 6-10 another, and so forth. If you don't have both the lower and upper bounds you cant find the price you are after with a single lookup, which should be your goal.

Comment: yes, i added min and max qty. But still i think there's a better solution to improve it. Looking for suggestions ;)

Comment: I've found in the past that anything that tries to apply all sorts of base / discount / rebate / clawback etc rules quickly becomes an unwieldy beast. Really hard to work out what the final price should be, particularly where there are conflicting rules (which if the marketing department is involved will be likely!)